# Angular redux/forms bind to nested element

Tags: angular, forms, angular-forms, angular-redux

I'm currently trying to bind a form to my redux store following [this](https://github.com/angular-redux/form)( template driven)

so lets say i have the following structure:

```
{   
 person {
  personName: string,
  address {
   street: string,
   city: string
  }
 }
}
```

Now i want to bind this to a form:

```
<form [connect]=['person']>
 <input type="text" name="personName">
 <!-- now i want to show the street and city -->
 <input type="text" name="street">
 <input type="text" name="city">
</form>
```

How do i tell the form that i want to add `address` to the path so i can bind `street`and `city`to my store?

Comment: have you already some typescript code inside your controller?

Comment: my controller? are you thinking angular 1.x?

Comment: no i think in angular 2 - 5 (i am talking about that typescript class named like your component)

Comment: yes, my component does contain some logic, but none of which affects this

Comment: and how do you receive that `person`?

Comment: the `person` is the root element in my store

Answer (score 0):

So i found the solution:

```
<form [connect]=['person']>
  <input type="text" name="personName">
  <!-- now i want to show the street and city -->
  <div [ngModelGroup]="'address'">
   <input type="text" name="street">
   <input type="text" name="city">
  </div>
</form>
```

I pass the `address` as a string to the modelGroup and this creates the necessary link in the path